# How to Pass Parameters to screen in StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My React Native code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, ListView, 
  Text, Button, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import DetailsPage from './src/screens/DetailsPage';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

   constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      userDataSource: ds,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.fetchUsers();
  }

    fetchUsers(){

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    userDataSource: this.state.userDataSource.cloneWithRows(response)
                });
            });
    }

    onPress(user){
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'DetailPage'
        });
    }

  renderRow(user, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow){
      return(
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.onPress(user)} } >
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text style={styles.rowText}> {user.name} </Text>

      </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      )
  }


  render(){
      return(
          <ListView
            dataSource = {this.state.userDataSource}
            renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}
          />
      )
  } 
}
```

Navigation config:

```
const NavigationTest = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  DetailsPage: { screen: DetailsPage },
});
```

The Details screens is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import styles from '../styles';


export default class DetailsPage extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `User: ${navigation.state.params.user.name}`,
  });
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.myStyle}>Name: {params.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.myStyle}>Email: {params.email}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am not able to pass the `user` to the `DetailsPage` with the code:

```
onPress(user){
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'DetailPage'
        });
    }
```

I want to navigate to the `DetailPage` with the `onPress` function. If I alert it like:

```
onPress(user){ Alert.alert(user.name)}
```

I do get the value, but how do I pass it to the other page?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can pass params with the `navigate` function's second argument:

```
onPress(user) {
  this.props.navigation.navigate(
    'DetailPage',
    { user },
  );
}
```

## React Navigation 5.x, 6.x (2022)

Access them in `this.props.route.params`. For example in your `DetailsPage`:

```
<Text style={styles.myStyle}>{this.props.route.params.user.name}</Text>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

## React Navigation <= 4.x

Access them in `this.props.navigation.state.params`. For example in your `DetailsPage`:

```
<Text style={styles.myStyle}>{this.props.navigation.state.params.user.name}</Text>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params/

Comment: Thanks. I was getting an error, I tried `'DetailPage', { users:user });` and It worked. I have another question if you could help please. Im trying to use a parameter from the user array, `id` to `fetch` data from another API, where and how can I use it? Trying to use it out of `fetch` by declaring, `var theId = '${navigation.state.params.users.id}` but its not working. Can you point me to the proper direction please? Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like a typo, try `${navigation.state.params.user.id}` (`user` instead of `users`)

Comment: No, I've passed it as `users`, `'DetailPage', { users:user });`. Not sure where and how do I call for it in the `fetch`, please help.

Comment: I have added a button on HeaderRigh property in Static navigation options in component on that button i want to pass ref of method defined in component. But i am not able to pass that. Can you help

Comment: @RobinGarg that's off topic, but you'll find the solution to your problem in this github issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/147

Comment: @Somename I have same issue: Trying to retain 'this' inside fetching of info. Been stuck on it for days, get's caught up in the Worker rather than the proper scope of where the function is binded

Comment: any replacement for getParams in react navigation 5 as it says undefined method?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal You can substitute `this.props.navigation.getParam('foo', 'bar')` for `this.props.route.params.foo || 'bar'`.

Answer (score 12):

[See this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators) .

It solved my problem.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("**stack_Name**", {
 screen:"screen_name_connect_with_**stack_name**",
 params:{
 user:"anything_string_or_object"
}
})
```

Comment: This is exactly the way to navigate. Very useful. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Here I have tried to pass param value with key, But it throws an syntax error.

Leike => 
params:{
 "anything_string_or_object"
}

Comment: Thanks, it is the exactly what I was seeking for that.

Answer (score 11):

In react hooks, params send in navigation using useNavigation

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = useNavigation();

<Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate('MyScreen',{name:'test'});
      }}
    />
```

then access them using  useNavigationParam

```
function MyScreen() {
  const name = useNavigationParam('name');
  return <p>name is {name}</p>;
}
```

Comment: useNavigationParam is not defined anywhere in the official docs, it was removed or not present

Answer (score 2):

In your first page, say CountriesList

```
const CountriesList = ({ navigation }) => {

/* Function to navigate to 2nd screen */
  const viewCountry = (country) => {
    navigation.navigate('ListItemPageRoute', { name: country.country_name });
  };
}
```

For your second page name, say ListItemPageRoute

```
const ListItemPageRoute = (props) => {

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.countryText}> { props.route.params.name } </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

'Props.route' Object will have the list of all parameters you would like to pass from one screen to another.

Comment: props.route.params  yes

Answer (score 1):

for me, soved it by useNavigation() and useRoute():

For functional component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

**For class component:**

```
class MyText extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Get it from props
    const { route } = this.props;
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const route = useRoute();

  return <MyText {...props} route={route} />;
}
```

Comment: const route = useRoute() is what worked for me as well, as opposed to what the docs say.

Answer (score 0):

onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('AllImages', {Types: item.type })}
console.log('values**strong text**', this.props.route.params.Types);**

Answer (score 0):

1)How to send data to another screen through params :
onPress={(item) => props.navigation.navigate('Your ScreenName', {item : item})}

2)How to get data on another screen:
const {item} = props.route.params

Answer (score 0):

in the current screen call

```
const CurrentScreen = ({navigation})=>{
   navigation.navigate('TargetScreen', {phone});
}
```

in the other side you can get it on route params

```
const TargetScreen = ({navigation, route})=>{
   console.log(route.params.phone) // the phone number is just hire
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it so easily.
You want to pass some parameters to your screen ? Do just that:

```js
export default () => {
  
  const MainScreenComponent = ({navigation}) => (
    <MainScreen
      navigation={navigation}
      /**
      *
      * And here your parameters...
      *
      */
    />
  );

  const HomeScreenComponent = ({navigation}) => (
    <HomeScreen
      navigation={navigation}
      /**
      *
      * And here your parameters...
      *
      */
    />
  );

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MainScreen">
        <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreenComponent}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={MomeScreenComponent}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```