# React Navigation v6: Where can I set param values in a class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm using react-navigation v6 in my React Native app, and in [this section](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params) on passing params to screens, it shows that you can get `itemId` and `otherParam` from `route.params` and set their values such that you can use `itemId` and `otherParam` throughout the component.

```
function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  /* 2. Get the param */
  const { itemId, otherParam } = route.params;
```

**What I Want To Know:** If I'm using a class component instead of a functional one, where can I set `itemId` and `otherParam`? As in, is there a place in a class component where I could run `const { itemId, otherParam } = this.props.route.params;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/45390937/1667803

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Pass Parameters to screen in StackNavigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388957/how-to-pass-parameters-to-screen-in-stacknavigator)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CommonActions` from import and `navigation` from `this.props.navigation` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#setparams

```js
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch({
  ...CommonActions.setParams({ user: 'Wojtek' }),
  source: route.key,
});
```