# Stack navigation send params between screens

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Im trying to send strings and objects between scenes, im currently using stack navigation.
Currently not recieving the params when changing screens, heres some part of the code:

Login

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Touchable,
  Image,
  Alert, 
  Pressable, 
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";
import { sendData } from "./Posts";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";

export type StackParamList = {

    Profile: { userId: string };
    ScreenFirst: { prueba1: string};
};

type Props = {

    navigation: StackNavigationProp<StackParamList,'Profile' >;
    
}

function Login({navigation} : Props): JSX.Element  {
    
    const send = async () => {
       navigation.replace('ScreenFirst', { prueba1:"texto1" })
    };

    return (
        <View>
           <TouchableOpacity style={styles.login} onPress={send}>
              <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>
                 Login
              </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
  login: {
    width: 63,
    height: 28,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(143,9,23,1)",
    borderRadius: 3,
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
  },
  btnLogin: {
    color: "white"
  },
});

export default Login;
```

ScreenFirst:

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { Pressable, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { sendData } from "./Posts";
import { TextInput } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { useState } from "react";
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

export type StackParamList = {

    Profile: { userId: string };
    ScreenFirst: undefined;
    Login: undefined;
};

type Props = {

    navigation: StackNavigationProp<StackParamList,'Profile' >;
    
}


function App({navigation} : Props): JSX.Element {
    const dataParse = useRoute().params;
    console.log(navigation.getState.arguments);
    console.log(dataParse);
    console.log(navigation.getState, useRoute());

    return (
      <View>
      </View>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Already tried to user "function App({route, navigation} : Props): JSX.Element" and isnt working.
Also tried some more things but nothing seems to be working, im always getting an "undefined" when doing the console.log. Heres what it prints:
LOG  undefined
LOG  undefined
LOG  [Function anonymous] {"key": "ScreenFirst-7Um3TSrbi489zPpwCrXAo", "name": "ScreenFirst", "params": undefined}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Pass Parameters to screen in StackNavigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388957/how-to-pass-parameters-to-screen-in-stacknavigator)

Answer (score 0):

send don't has to be async:

```
    const send = () => {
           navigation.replace('ScreenFirst', { prueba1:"texto1" })
};
```

Try using following implementation:

```
function App({route,navigation} : Props): JSX.Element {
    const dataParse = route.params;

    console.log(dataParse);

    return (
      <View>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thats not working, first of all im getting an error
`property 'route' does not exist on type 'Props'.ts(2339)
(parameter) route: any`.
So i tried solving it by adding route: `RouteProp<StackParamList, 'Profile'>;` but still getting undefined